# Format an integer to use currency then ORDER BY DESC

Tags: mysql, format, numbers

I am trying to order numerical values by DESC order and for the most part the below query does the job, except for a few numbers that are out of order.

```
    "SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(soldprice, 0)) AS soldprice FROM wp_previous_listings WHERE wp_previous_listings.main_email = '". $current_email ."' ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(soldprice) DESC"
```

The values for soldprice in the db are integers(saved as a double) (no commas or $). I format soldprice to have $ and commas added in the query using CONCAT, then count the length of each soldprice for ordering purposes.

Current Output

```
    $10,450,000
    $4,400,000
    $1,700,000
    $1,287,500
    $8,800,000
    $8,750,000
    $6,669,828
    $5,200,000
    $4,850,000
```

Expected Output

```
    $10,450,000
    $8,800,000
    $6,669,828
    $5,200,000
    $4,850,000
    $4,400,000
    $1,700,000
    $1,287,500
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: `ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH()` ??? try `ORDER BY soldprice`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Tried that already and ordering was a train wreck.

Comment: So what data type is the `soldprice` column in your database

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see now, you call your alias the same name as the actual column name in the DB, and that has a `$` concatentated onto it so its a String now, and strings representaions of numbers dont sort like real numbers.

So go for

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(soldprice, 0)) AS sp 
FROM wp_previous_listings 
WHERE wp_previous_listings.main_email = '". $current_email ."' 
ORDER BY soldprice DESC"
```

I personally would have dont the currency concatenation in the PHP rather than the SQL, but whatever

> Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
> You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CHAR_LENGTH has to do with this. Since the column is already a number, just sort by that:

```
"SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(soldprice, 0)) AS soldprice FROM wp_previous_listings WHERE wp_previous_listings.main_email = '". $current_email ."' ORDER BY soldprice DESC"
```

Comment: I tried LENGTH AND CHAR_LENGTH thinking that I could count the length of each number and then sort that way.

Comment: @shuss Those functions are for getting how long a string is. Your column is a number. Use the ORDER BY clause in my answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, wont work because `soldprice` is now a string with a `$` at the front due to the CONCAT() alias being called the same as the actual table column that the sort is on. Of course its a string now and they dont sort the same as numbers

Comment: This has been solved. soldprice was being outputted as a string even though it was saved as an INT. To solve, I added a +0 after soldprice to convert to an integer.  "SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(soldprice, 0)) AS soldprice FROM wp_previous_listings WHERE wp_previous_listings.main_email = '". $current_email ."' ORDER BY soldprice+0 DESC"